# How to create a tf.data.Datasets for linear regression and train model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Can I train a linear regression model with tf.data.Datasets? If I run the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 10, num=10**2)
y = 54*x + 33

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(zip(x, y)))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape = [1,]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="sigmoid"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="adam")
model.fit(ds, epochs=5)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Target data is missing. Your model was compiled with loss=mean_absolute_error, and therefore expects target data to be provided in `fit()`.
```

It is possible to train like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider:

1. Create `dataset` like `from_tensor_slices((x,y))`
2. Define and take `dataset` with batch, like : `ds = ds.batch(32)`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 10, num=10**2)
y = 54*x + 33

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y))
ds = ds.batch(32)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape = [1,]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="sigmoid"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="adam")
model.fit(ds, epochs=5)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 329.4714
Epoch 2/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 329.4355
Epoch 3/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 329.3994
Epoch 4/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 329.3628
Epoch 5/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 329.3259
```

**Update:** *How to create a model and train for linear regression?*
You don't need a complex and large network only a `Dense(1)` with `activation='linear'` is OK.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(10000)
y = 54*x + 33

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y))
ds = ds.batch(64)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape = [1,]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
    ])

model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="adam")
model.fit(ds, epochs=50)
```

---

```
Epoch 1/50
157/157 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 60.0440
Epoch 2/50
157/157 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 59.6723
Epoch 3/50
157/157 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 59.1068
...
Epoch 48/50
157/157 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1588
Epoch 49/50
157/157 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0053
Epoch 50/50
157/157 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0039
```

Comment: Awesome!! can you please elaborate what went wrong with my code please?

Comment: @HashNuke, you create dataset with `list(zip(x, y))`, you don't need this.

Comment: Even if I remove the `ds = ds.batch(32)`, I get the error

Comment: @HashNuke, after creating a dataset whitout `ds = ds.batch(32)`, you got an error, because you don't have element and split dataset to batch to a model can take batch a learn on this.

Comment: I see, thank you so much! I learnt a new thing!!

Comment: @HashNuke, without : `ds = ds.batch(32)` you got this error : `expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=0. Full shape received: ()` this means you don't create batch on your dataset and model gets empty `()`